# Salt Command for encrypting passwords isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, password-hash

For our project we are trying to encrypt passwords using the salt  command, but it doesn't seem to be working. this is what we have so far:

```
<html>
<?php
$con=msqli_connect('XXXX', '<username>', '<password>', 'XXXXXXX');
// Create connection
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_erno($con));
{
    echo "Failed to connect to Mysql: " . msqli_connect_error();
}
?>  

<?php
$Password = $_POST['password'];

$salt = //


$password = sha1(userPasswordinput . salt);
?>
<head>

<title>Password Ecryption</title>
</head>

<body>


</body>
</html>
```

the connection to mysql is working, but apparently something is wrong. The password variable is posting from another code page, and that part is working as well.

Comment: We seem to be missing some essential parts of your code. What happens to `$Password` after it is populated from `$_POST['password']`?

Comment: $Password comes from the previous web code(which isn't displayed) and posts it in the database. I probably am going about this wrong, so i will explain what this code is supposed to be doing: This php code takes the password that the person input into the webpage this will be linked to and encrypts it to store it in the database to store so when someone logs in it encrypt what they type in and make sure it matches the already stored encrypted password. This was my best effort,

Comment: Where is `salt` (I'm assuming it's a constant) defined? And is `userPasswordinput` also a constant?

Comment: And I hope those aren't your real database credentials, especially as you're connecting as `root`

Comment: it isn't a DNS server. I'm not sure i understand your question.

Comment: @John - if you're careless enough to post db credentials publicly here, you could be careless enough to use those same credentials on accessible servers

Comment: @Mark unlikely, but i appreciate your concern. Is there supposed to be code after the // ?

Comment: @John - I was assuming you were defining $salt somehow, else you have a syntax error; but `$salt` is a variable, `salt` would be a constant value if defined as a constant, or a string containing the text "salt" if not (together with a warning)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors in your code which is preventing the salt and posted password from working correctly. Try the code below:

```
<?php
// lower case variable names for non-objects (developer preference)
$password_input = $_POST['password'];

// you had a syntax error here (missing variable value and ending semi-colon)
$salt = 'SomePasswordSaltString';

// you had another syntax error here (incorrect variable reference and missing $)
$password = sha1($password_input . $salt);
?>
```

Comment: now that i see it done, it makes so much more sense, thanks i will try it!!